# Tesco 8.9" Connect Tablet Touchscreen Driver

Tags: windows-10, tablet

I have a Tesco 8.9" Connect Tablet but I cannot find a driver for the touchscreen.

The device ID is MSSL 1680, it is running Windows 10.

Comment: I've been researching this for the past few days for you. Tesco's tech support is just awful. I have a couple of suggestions, check in the BIOS to see if touch has been accidentally disabled or try one of the 3rd party Win8.1 drivers from [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/windows-8-rt/general/silead-mssl-1680-t3116128). But only after sweeping them with AV.

Comment: Close voters: As a reminder, please review [this Meta post](https://meta.superuser.com/a/3822/213131) when deciding how to handle driver requests.

Answer (score 1):

[This page](https://ttselectrical.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/4275/c/38258%2C38265) on the official Tesco customer support site lists drivers for the Tesco (Viglen) Connect tablets, including the touchscreen driver.

If the above link breaks in future, try searching or browsing from the front page of the site at https://ttselectrical.custhelp.com.

Answer (score 0):

If your looking for the Touchscreen Driver, i managed to find one when i had trouble installing it myself on a customer's tablet.

Included is the Touchsetting.gt file and the drivers.

This is for the 10.1" style tablet which is 1GB DDR3, z3735f and 32GB storage
https://www.mediafire.com/?bc3drfm38wf9dud

Install this via device manager, browse for drivers (not search via windows update)

Answer (score 0):

I've extracted & uploaded all w10 drivers from my running viglen connect 8.9" tablet. May come in handy to some people.

http://www.mediafire.com/file/phrwje8hvm1ctux/Viglen_Connect_8point9_inch_W10_Drivers.rar

Comment: Read over ["Why do I need 50 reputation to comment"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead) to ensure you understand how you can start commenting.